# Chrome "RestoreOnStartup" policy shows status "Error, Ignored"

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to set Chrome startup option to "Continue where you left off" by setting registry value RestoreOnStartup in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome to 1. It works in most of my PCs except for two Windows 10 cloud PC, where chrome://policy shows RestoreOnStartup policy as "Error, Ignored". Why doesn't it work on these cloud PCs? Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does it help if you do "Reload policies" in the `chrome://policy` page?

Comment: No, it doesn't help.